# Copy lines by rows in awk

Tags: awk, row

I have an input file that contains, per row, a value and two weights.

I would like to generate two output files - where the value in the first column is repeated once per line, according to the weights. This is probably best explained with a short example.  If the input file is:

file.in:

```
35   2   0
37   2   3
38   0   4
```

Then I would like to generate two output files:

file.out1:

```
35 
35
37
37
```

file.out2:

```
37
37
37
38
38
38
38
```

I will then use these output files to calculate the average and median of first column according to the weights in the second and third column.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think the question is clear. Can you edit your question to try and explain the problem better?

Comment: You need average and median based on first column right?

Comment: Thank you guys for comment. I would like to  generate two output files - where the value in the first column is repeated once per line, according to the weights. The best answer gave me Floris - afters his output I am able to compute the median and average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy in `awk`.

```
awk '{for(i=0;i<$2;i++) print $1;}' file.in > file.out1
```

generates the first file, and

```
awk '{for(i=0;i<$3;i++) print $1;}' file.in > file.out2
```

generates the second

It is not clear from your question whether you know how to compute the mean and median from these files - it seems you just wanted to create these output files. Let me know if the rest is giving your trouble, or whether the above scripts are not clear (I think they are pretty self-explanatory).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well you need average and median.

Average:

```
awk '{a+=$1}END{print a/NR}' file.in
36.6667
```

Median:

```
cat file.in | awk '{print $1}' | sort | awk '{a[NR]=$1}END{ b=NR/2; b=b%1?int(b)+1:b; print a[b] }'
37
```

**Explanation:**

Putting in simple terms NR is a variable which keeps the number of lines, for average you want a sum of every line divided by the number of lines.

For median you want you input sorted and pick the median value, but it's not so simple for your input because I you divide number of lines which is 3 by 2 you will get 1.5 so you need a ceiling function which awk doesn't have so I am doing it with `b=NR/2; b=b%1?int(b)+1:b;`

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. OP is looking for a way to convert the input file into two output files where the value in the first column is repeated according to the second or third column. You can skip that step to compute a weighted mean, but it's not so easy to compute the median without having all the values and sorting. And that was not the thing he seemed to be struggling with.

Comment: I think he just need average and median and doesn't even know it could be done that way. WRT median you can see that I am sorting the values. Do you thing I am calculating median wrongly?

Comment: I think your answer is complementary to mine. You need to perform your calculations on `file.out1` and `file.out2`, not on `file.in`.

Comment: Yeah right - thank you Floris - this works for me perfectly fine - right now I am able to compute average and median.